# Angular Controls and Plugins

Tags: angular, plugins, controls, frontend

For all your Angular frontend developers, where do you usually get resources from?
eg. data tables, wizard style step through pages, drag and drop uploads, etc

Comment: go and search in google man

Comment: That is what I have been doing. Most of the plugins are either deprecated or under development, so i usually spend heaps of time trying to tweak it. This is really question off-the-shelf product like Telerik vs open source projects.